# chrome.omnibox ceases working after period of time. Begins working after restarting extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm leveraging Google Chrome's [omnibox API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/omnibox) in my extension.

Current users, including myself, have noticed that the omnibox ceases responding entirely after an undetermined state change or a period of time lapsing. Typing the word to trigger entering into "omnibox" stops having any effect and the URL bar does not shift into omnibox mode.

Restarting Google Chrome does not fix the issue, but restarting my plugin by unchecking and then re-checking the 'enabled' checkbox on chrome://extensions does resolve the issue.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what to investigate? Below is the code used. It is only loaded once through my permanently persisted background page:

```
//  Displays streamus search suggestions and allows instant playing in the stream
define([
    'background/collection/streamItems',
    'background/model/video',
    'common/model/youTubeV2API',
    'common/model/utility'
], function (StreamItems, Video, YouTubeV2API, Utility) {
    'use strict';

    console.log("Omnibox LOADED", chrome.omnibox);

    var Omnibox = Backbone.Model.extend({

        defaults: function () {
            return {
                suggestedVideos: [],
                searchJqXhr: null
            };
        },

        initialize: function () {
            console.log("Omnibox INITIALIZED");
            var self = this;

            chrome.omnibox.setDefaultSuggestion({
                //  TODO: i18n
                description: 'Press enter to play.'
            });

            //  User has started a keyword input session by typing the extension's keyword. This is guaranteed to be sent exactly once per input session, and before any onInputChanged events.
            chrome.omnibox.onInputChanged.addListener(function (text, suggest) {

                //  Clear suggested videos
                self.get('suggestedVideos').length = 0;

                var trimmedSearchText = $.trim(text);

                //  Clear suggestions if there is no text.
                if (trimmedSearchText === '') {
                    suggest();
                } else {

                    //  Do not display results if searchText was modified while searching, abort old request.
                    var previousSearchJqXhr = self.get('searchJqXhr');

                    if (previousSearchJqXhr) {
                        previousSearchJqXhr.abort();
                        self.set('searchJqXhr', null);
                    }

                    var searchJqXhr = YouTubeV2API.search({
                        text: trimmedSearchText,
                        //  Omnibox can only show 6 results
                        maxResults: 6,
                        success: function(videoInformationList) {
                            self.set('searchJqXhr', null);

                            var suggestions = self.buildSuggestions(videoInformationList, trimmedSearchText);

                            suggest(suggestions);

                        }
                    });

                    self.set('searchJqXhr', searchJqXhr);
                }

            });

            chrome.omnibox.onInputEntered.addListener(function (text) {

                //  Find the cached video data by url
                var pickedVideo = _.find(self.get('suggestedVideos'), function(suggestedVideo) {
                    return suggestedVideo.get('url') === text;
                });

                //  If the user doesn't make a selection (commonly when typing and then just hitting enter on their query)
                //  take the best suggestion related to their text.
                if (pickedVideo === undefined) {
                    pickedVideo = self.get('suggestedVideos')[0];
                }

                StreamItems.addByVideo(pickedVideo, true);

            });

        },

        buildSuggestions: function(videoInformationList, text) {
            var self = this;

            var suggestions = _.map(videoInformationList, function (videoInformation) {

                var video = new Video({
                    videoInformation: videoInformation
                });
                self.get('suggestedVideos').push(video);

                var safeTitle = _.escape(video.get('title'));
                var textStyleRegExp = new RegExp(Utility.escapeRegExp(text), "i");
                var styledTitle = safeTitle.replace(textStyleRegExp, '<match>$&</match>');

                var description = '<dim>' + video.get('prettyDuration') + "</dim>  " + styledTitle;

                return {
                    content: video.get('url'),
                    description: description
                };
            });

            return suggestions;
        }
    });

    return new Omnibox();
});
```

As far as I'm aware the code itself is fine and wouldn't have any effect on whether I see omnibox or not.

You can find full source code here: https://github.com/MeoMix/StreamusChromeExtension/blob/master/src/js/background/model/omnibox.js

Comment: I was seeing this in one of my extensions for a while but haven't noticed it in a while. I'm running the Chrome beta channel so it might be fixed.

Comment: That seems to align with what I'm seeing. I'm on beta at home and stable at the office and I was seeing it at the office, but never at home!

Comment: It still happens so it seems, rendering my extension useless LoL.